# What does 'What kind of mischief are you up to?' mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, idioms

One of my US users asked the following questions when she got information about my resignation from my manager.

> What is this rumor I hear? What kind of mischief are you up to?

I am not sure whether she is asking what I did wrong or what others did wrong by taking the resignation decision.

Can somebody explain me the meaning of this sentence in this situation.

Comment: She just wants to know what you are up to and why the resignation. *Mischief* here basically refers to any discreet plans you may have after leaving the current organisation and which may have prompted your resignation.

Comment: How is this off topic? See the tags, folks.

Comment: Thanks Mohit and Kris.  I tried to explain the situation so that i can get the better answer. Anyway thanks again for answering my question.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a light-hearted inquiry. The jestful implication is that you're leaving to go stir up some kind of trouble. She's asking "What kind of trouble are you going to cause?" But I stress, this is a common, friendly, thing to say. Think of it as a farewell.